# Azure storage file "Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported." "AuthenticationFailed"

Tags: azure, api, file, storage

I am trying to consume Azure file api "https://"mystorageaccountname".file.core.windows.net/?comp=list"

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-shares

Authentication method: OAuth 2.0

- I have Generated "Authorization Code" and also "Access Token".

  link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code
- Created Resource of Azure Ad Domain Service

  link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-getting-started
- Enabled the "Azure Active Directory authentication for Azure Files" in my storage account.

  link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/storage/files/storage-files-active-directory-enable

Headers:

- Authorization:Bearer eyJ0.................
- x-ms-date:Tuesday, 23 Apr 2019 11:35:45 GMT
- x-ms-version:2018-03-28

Error:

```
<Error>

<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>

    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

RequestId:40fcb1a8-301a-000d-67c8-f9f4b5000000

Time:2019-04-23T11:35:52.9358422Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>

Authentication scheme Bearer is not supported.

</AuthenticationErrorDetail>

</Error>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the `x-ms-version` header to your call to the Storage Account.

For example (in PowerShell):

```
Invoke-WebRequest $url -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $access_token"; "x-ms-version" = "2020-04-08" } -OutFile $outputFilePath
```

Comment: The `x-ms-version` header was indeed what I was missing

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting this error is because currently Azure AD based authorization for Azure Files is only supported over `SMB` protocol. It is still not supported via `REST API`.

For REST API, Azure AD based authorization is only supported for Blob and Queue service as of now. [Read the matrix of storage account authorizations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-requests-to-azure-storage).

Comment: I used hte blob storage url and it still gives the same error

Comment: Getting the same error for Queue, using Bearer